# since one or two days opera does not store passwords anymore

Tags: browser

opera used to save passwords but does not so any more.
"offer to save passwords" is checked, but does not work.
No saved passwords are shown.
Installing an older opera-version (opera-stable_62.0.3331.99 instead of opera-stable_74.0.3911.2180) did not help.

Comment: You may be better off asking here https://www.opera.com/help

Comment: Do prefer to use a password manager to having a browser save passwords.  Browser's saving passwords did have not nice things said about them before, might be better now.  Password managers work on all browsers, so you can use opera, firefox, and chrome and passwords will be the same on all.

Comment: Voting to close, as the issue resolved itself.